Sum with conditions and iterations
I need to use Sum in a unique way. Say we have a number $N$ passed in, I want to calculate and add all these series:
$$N^2$$
plus
$$
1+2+\cdots+(N-1)+ \\
1+2+\cdots+(N-2)+ \\
1+2+\cdots+(N-3)+ \\
\vdots \\
+1
$$
plus
$$
1+2+\cdots+(N-3)+ \\
1+2+\cdots+(N-5)+\\
1+2+\cdots+(N-7)+\\
\vdots \\
+1
$$
In such a fashion so that those series stay positive always! For example if $N=8$, then both those go until the $(N-7)$  which is literally $1$  (the last terms).
If $N=1$, both series will not exist (as middle one will be $0=N-1$ and last one will be $-2=N-3$) etc.
I want to represent this with one nice Sum with those conditions. Then I assume we can FullSimplify it!

It looks like you are looking for the following expression:
$$S = n^2 + \sum _{k=1}^{n-1} \sum _{i=1}^{n-k} i + \sum _{k=1}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n-2}{2}\right\rfloor } \sum _{i=0}^{n-(2 k+1)} i,$$
which can be evaluated to:
$$S = \frac{1}{6} \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor  \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor  \left(4 \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor -6 n-3\right)+3 n (n+1)-1\right)+n (n+1) (n+2)\right),$$
or more elegantly written as:
$$S = \begin{cases} 
 \frac{1}{6} \left(n^3-n\right)+n^2+\frac{1}{24} \left(2 n^3-9 n^2+10 n\right) & n \text{ is even,} \\
 \frac{1}{6} \left(n^3-n\right)+n^2+\frac{1}{24} \left(2 n^3-9 n^2+10 n-3\right) & n \text{ is odd.} \\
\end{cases}
$$
s = n^2 + Sum[i, {k, 1, n - 1}, {i, 1, n - k}] + 
  Sum[i, {k, 1, Floor[(n - 2)/2]}, {i, 0, n - (2*k + 1)}];
Table[{n, s}, {n, 1, 10}] // Grid
(*
  1     1
  2     5
  3     13
  4     27
  5     48
  6     78
  7     118
  8     170
  9     235
  10    315
*)


+1 Looking up the results in oeis.org finds sequence A002717:  Floor[n(n+2)(2n+1)/8].

Thanks @Domen, amazing aggregation into a simple series! Bravo.... Results look accurate.  Can it be Simplified by Mathematica to output the equations which you gave at the end?

@Steve237, I don't know whether there is a way to simplify Floor by assuming even or odd $n$ ... So I just manually replaced Floor[(n - 2)/2] with (n - 2)/2 for even and (n - 3)/2 for odd $n$.

Thanks, i mean the one with ODD and EVEN at the end...can Mathematica derive thsoe 2 equations?

Yes, as I said, just replace Floor[(n - 2)/2] in s with either of the two terms I mentioned. Mathematica will then give you the two expressions.
